# Update Manager terminal output tiny after upgrade to 16.10

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, 16.10

When I use the update manager to update packages after upgrading to 16.10, if I show details during the updates, the area of the window that displays the terminal output is so small I can only see one line of text.

EDIT:
So it seems that the real problem is that it will only shrink with changes in the size of the window, not expand.  If the window is big enough when the terminal output thing is added, it will start at the right size.  The download progress detail view seems to be also affected.

Example images:
[image: terminal output]
[image: downloading packages]

Comment: Add yourself to the bug 1640717.   It starts out with the technical description being the wrong size (which I noticed on my 16.10 after reading the bug).  I'm using nouveau drivers, plain 16.10 desktop.